# Removing zero quantity items from Netsuite Picking Ticket Advanced PDF

Tags: templates, pdf, printing, netsuite

I am new to NetSuite and my current role. Our warehouse team is strunggling with Picking Tickets coming through with zero quantity items among a long list of items to be picked.

Pickers are making mistakes and picking items for which an order has not been placed. The original problem is with the Sales Order which is being worked on by others.

I am trying to find a quick solution whereby when picking tickets are printed the zero quantity items are filtered out and not printed.

Really appreciate any help provided.

Answer (score 1):

Try this "SHOW UNCOMMITTED ITEMS ON PICKING TICKETS"
Navigation: setup--> Accounting-->Accounting preferences-->order management

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this, you can also add this code to the PDF template in the case where you still need the uncommitted line items in Netsuite but just not printed on the PDF:

```
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th>...</th>
   <tr/>
</thead>
<!-- only line items with qty > 0 on Sales Order will print -->
<#if item.quantity gt 0>
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
</#if>
```